# Django safe to exempt csrf?

Tags: python, django, security, rest, csrf

I am using Django framework for my backend support for a mobile app. 

I choose to use the original Django's `views.py` to get my API url mapping and dump JSON for response, rather than using other REST frameworks like `Django REST Framwork` or `TastiPie`.

Now if I make a cross domain HTTP Request from my mobile client app. normally I will get a `403 Forbidden` error because of Django's built-in CSRF protection. It seems like it can only work when I exempt it explicitly before each function in `views.py`. My question is, is it safe to exempt the protection? If exempt csrf is not a good way to do, what suggestions do you have on my situation?

Thanks

Comment: Do you understand the dangers of CSRF attacks?

Comment: Hi @SLaks yes I do know a little. But could this risk be reduced due to two factors? 1. I can have an api key built in to my mobile app, as my mobile app is the only consumer of the APIs. 2. this sub-domain is only for api and contains no web page view.

Comment: CSRF is only a problem if you have cookies that users may have in a browser.  If you don't have auth cookies, there is no attack.